# How to separate a column of strings into multiple columns, each containing a single char of a string, with strings of unequal length and no separator?

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-munging

My data frame is this:

```
data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
       A = c("1234", "abc.", "e-2.1ad"),
       B = c("5-4", "1-0", "a,d")
)
```

I want to separate the columns into multiple columns containing individual characters.

The other answers that I found, all involved using some regular expression or pattern or separator, which as you see, I can't do here, or convoluted solutions using `sapply` (which used the position, but for me it didn't work). 
I'm sure there's a more elegant solution out there and I would really love a solution using `tidyr` if possible, but whatever does it cleanly is much appreciated.

This is what it should like, after all is said and done:

```
 newdf <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      A1 = c("1", "a", "e"),
      A2 = c("2", "b", "-"),
      A3 = c("3", "c", "2"),
      A4 = c("4", ".", "."),
      A5 = c(NA, NA, 1),
      A6 = c(NA, NA, "a"),
      A7 = c(NA, NA, "d"),
      B1 = c("5", "1", "a"),
      B2 = c("-", "-", ","),
      B3 = c("4", "0", "d")
)
```

And, if the answer is more than throwing a function or two at it, I would really appreciate if you could explain how you go about it, rather than just the solution itself. Thank you!

Later edit: I was able to almost do it using the `qdap` package but I could get around it filling what should've been NAs (because of the strings' unequal lengths) with characters from the beginning of the string. Very odd behavior which wasn't explained in the documentation, otherwise a very promising function.

Another strange behavior that I noticed in my lame attempts to solve this was automatically transforming from characters into factors. However, I wasn't able to pinpoint where it happens along the way.

Comment: What happens to the 32 in "5-432"?

Comment: @Elin! Thank you for noticing. It was an error on my side. I deleted the extra "32" now to make it simple. Originally, it should've mean that B needed other 3 columns, B4 and B5, with 3 and 2 in the first row, and NAs in the other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of potential options, depending on details of what you are interested in. See @Elin's comment above regarding missing 32 in 5-432.

One possibility to consider is `str_split_fixed` from `stringr` package:

```
str_split_fixed("1234", "", 7)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  ""   ""   ""
```

An empty pattern "" would split by character, and in this case try to return 7 pieces as a character matrix (with the last 3 empty strings). Right now, if no character is available, it returns an empty string, not NA. (see [github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/195)).

If the number of columns was based on the maximum number of characters possible for columns A and B (7 and 5 for example), one could do the following:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) str_split_fixed(x, "", n=max(nchar(x)))))

  A.1 A.2 A.3 A.4 A.5 A.6 A.7 B.1 B.2 B.3 B.4 B.5
1   1   2   3   4               5   -   4   3   2
2   a   b   c   .               1   -   0        
3   e   -   2   .   1   a   d   a   ,   d
```

Note: To replace the empty strings afterwards with NA:

```
df[df==""] <- NA

  A.1 A.2 A.3 A.4  A.5  A.6  A.7 B.1 B.2 B.3  B.4  B.5
1   1   2   3   4 <NA> <NA> <NA>   5   -   4    3    2
2   a   b   c   . <NA> <NA> <NA>   1   -   0 <NA> <NA>
3   e   -   2   .    1    a    d   a   ,   d <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've chosen yours as the answer because it seems the cleanest and shortest way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my `tidyverse` solutions. Writing a function is new to me, any suggestions for improvement would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        A = c("1234", "abc.", "e-2.1ad"),
        B = c("5-432", "1-0", "a,d"))    

a_split<- str_split(df$A, "")
b_split<- str_split(df$B, "")
f1 <- function(num, s)(c(s[[1]][num], s[[2]][num], s[[3]][num]))
x <- c(1:7)
all_a <- lapply(x, f1, a_split)
x <- c(1:5)
all_b <- lapply(x, f1, b_split)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. You're definitely very gifted with R, given the ease and focus of your writing functions. I appreciate your effort in helping me with this problem!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` and split every character in column `A` and `B` into separate column

```
df1 <- splitstackshape::cSplit(df, c('A', 'B'), sep = '', stripWhite = FALSE)
df1

#   A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 A_5  A_6  A_7 B_1 B_2 B_3 B_4 B_5 B_6 B_7
#1:   1   2   3   4  NA <NA> <NA>   5   -   4   3   2  NA  NA
#2:   a   b   c   .  NA <NA> <NA>   1   -   0  NA  NA  NA  NA
#3:   e   -   2   .   1    a    d   a   ,   d  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

However, this gave me some additional columns with `NA` for `B` which can be removed using `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), df1)
#   A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 A_5  A_6  A_7 B_1 B_2 B_3 B_4 B_5
#1:   1   2   3   4  NA <NA> <NA>   5   -   4   3   2
#2:   a   b   c   .  NA <NA> <NA>   1   -   0  NA  NA
#3:   e   -   2   .   1    a    d   a   ,   d  NA  NA
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
             A = c("1234", "abc.", "e-2.1ad"),
             B = c("5-432", "1-0", "a,d"))
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is almost identical with Ben's, above. It helped a lot, but I can only indicate one answer. In all honesty, I have no rational reason for choosing Ben's over yours, besides it being the first on the page and you already having a high status (votes and all)... For not being able to come up with better reasons, I'm sorry but I hope you'll take my thanks!

Comment: PS: you also noticed the problem in col B but interpreted it correctly and still gave a solution... That says a lot of your expertise. Where do I make a request for voting two elegant solutions instead of just being limited to one... ;) Thank you again.

Comment: Using `cSplit` is a great answer here. Will upvote. I have learned a lot from @Ronak.